# List users in tenant

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

```js
var auth = require('./auth');
var graph = require('./graph');

// Get an access token for the app.
auth.getAccessToken().then(function (token) {
  // Get all of the users in the tenant.
  graph.getUsers(token)
    .then(function (users) {
      // Create an event on each user's calendar.
      graph.createEvent(token, users);
    }, function (error) {
      console.error('>>> Error getting users: ' + error);
    });
}, function (error) {
  console.error('>>> Error getting access token: ' + error);
});
```

I am using this [Microsoft Graph Node.js](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-apponlytoken-rest-sample) sample.

The ultimate goal is to be able to list all the users in the organization/tenant and create an event on each of their calendars.

I am currently able to obtain an access token (which appeared to be the most difficult part) which is listed in the terminal in VSCode. However, I am having trouble accessing the users in the organization and have that listed in the terminal as well. I have the following URI `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName` that gets all the users in my organization in the Microsoft Graph Explorer. But using this same URI isn't working in my application.

I have all the proper permissions specified in Azure the only roadblock is listing the users in the organization.

Here is my code that is supposed to reference the users in the organization and creates a calendar event accordingly.

```js
var request = require('request');
var Q = require('q');

// The graph module object.
var graph = {};


// Make a request to get all users in the tenant/organization. 
graph.getUsers = function (token, users) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  request.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName', {
    auth: {
      bearer: token,

    }
  }, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error");
      } 

      else {
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);

        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
          console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
      }
        else {
          // The value of the body will be an array of all users.
          console.log("Users = " + parsedBody.value)
        }
      }

    });

  return deferred.promise;
};


//Creates an event on each user's calendar.
graph.createEvent = function (token, users) {
  var i;
  var startTime;
  var endTime;
  var newEvent;
  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    // The new event will be 30 minutes and take place tomorrow at the current time.
    startTime = new Date();
    startTime.setDate(startTime.getDate() + 1);
    endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + 30 * 60000);

    // These are the fields of the new calendar event.
    newEvent = {
      Subject: 'Creating Event test',
      Location: {
        DisplayName: "Edison Ballroom"
      },
      Start: {
        DateTime: startTime,
        TimeZone: 'PST'
      },
      End: {
        DateTime: endTime,
        TimeZone: 'PST'
      },
      Body: {
        Content: 'This is a test for adding calendar events. Thanks!',
        ContentType: 'Text'
      }
    };

    // Add an event to the current user's calendar.
    request.post({
      url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + users[i].id + '/events',
      headers: {
        contenttype: 'application/json',
        authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        displayName: users[i].displayName
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newEvent)
    }, function (err, response, body) {
      var parsedBody;
      var displayName;
      if (err) {
        console.error('>>> Application error: ' + err);
      } else {
        parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        displayName = response.request.headers.displayName;

        if (parsedBody.error) {
          if (parsedBody.error.code === 'RequestBroker-ParseUri') {
            console.error(
              '>>> Error creating an event for ' + displayName +
              '. Most likely due to this user having a MSA instead of an Office 365 account.'
            );
          } else {
            console.error(
              '>>> Error creating an event for ' + displayName + '.' + parsedBody.error.message
            );
          }
        } else {
          console.log('>>> Successfully created an event on ' + displayName + "'s calendar.");
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

module.exports = graph;
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: There is no current error, the roadblock is that the list of users in the organization is not being read or listed in the terminal like the access token. I showed the snippet to see if I missed a reference or something along those lines. Its as if the url in the snippet is not being read at all.

Comment: You are indeed calling the method right? graph.getUsers?

Comment: Yes. So far it recognizes and generates an access token. But it doesn't recognize the graph file to list the users and add an event to their calendars. I have added the app.js file to the original question.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hey! Do you mind sharing what was the solution?

Comment: As silly as it sounds, I tried redownloading the snippets with the same modifications made previously and it worked. So if anyone else has issues with this same tutorial try redownloading it if you have any issues. Thanks.